# UIImagePickerController Causes Autolayout Errors with Video Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a UIImagePickerController that can bring up the camera, photo album, or video controls.  There are no issues with the camera or photo album; however, when the Apple video controls are brought up a ton of autolayout errors show in the debugger.  This is Apple's stock view and not something I can control.  Here are the errors it shows:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>
> (
>
> ```
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x198b4b60 V:|-(11)-[CAMFlipButton:0x156d6300]   (Names: '|':CAMBottomBar:0x1988e810 )>",
>
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1989c060 CAMShutterButton:0x198a30b0.centerY == CAMBottomBar:0x1988e810.centerY>",
>
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19869eb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[PLImagePickerCameraView:0x162e8600(0)]>",
>
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x157e44e0 CAMBottomBar:0x1988e810.height == PLImagePickerCameraView:0x162e8600.height>",
>
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x157f80e0 V:[CAMFlipButton:0x156d6300]-(0)-[UIView:0x1986a9a0]>",
>
>    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15732e50 UIView:0x1986a9a0.bottom == CAMShutterButton:0x198a30b0.top>"
> ```
>
> )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>
> The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Again this is standard controller instantiated as such:

```
self.mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"camera"] || [mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    else self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"])
    {
        self.mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        [self.mediaPicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30.0f];
    }
    else
        self.mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    self.mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Have exactly the same problem on a iPad2. Did you find any solution or is it a temporary bug in Apple's side that we can ignore?

Comment: It appears to be on Apple's side and there isn't anything we can do.  Fortunately, besides being annoying in the debugger, it doesn't cause user related issues.